# Cannot find what is making the website load unusually slow

Tags: wordpress

I've been tasked with finding out what is stalling this website or making it load stupidly slow.

I've tried the network tab of the Google Chrome inspector, but I cannot figure out what is causing the initial delay.

Code has been optimised (further optimisation to come) and plugins have been added or removed and updates. Yet still slow.

URL is https://simplybikestuff.com/

Can anyone shed any light or suggest anything?

Caching plugins tried: WP Fastest Cache, WP Optimise (inc. database optimise and image smushing).

Comment: Your initial page load time -- to deliver the basic HTML page for the site -- is repeatably about 8 seconds.  That is very long, and it is the first issue to address. It's hard to help you further; you haven't given us much to go on except your URL. Suggestion for troubleshooting: install and activate the Query Monitor plugin, then display the slow page (it's the front door page). You may get some insight into slow queries.

Comment: Your front door page has some elaborate hover menus. It's possible your WordPress / php server is doing tons of work to populate those menus. It looks like you use the Mega Menus plugin. You could try, on a test site, disabling that plugin. Does doing so shorten your initial page load?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reduce chaining critical request https://prnt.sc/Nnyf4hnHmYpX.
You can try WP Rocket Caching plugin for optimization.

Comment: Thankyou, I'll try this. So WP Rocket automatically optimises the critical request chain?

Comment: Welcome to SO ! could you share the code in your answer rather than sending the link to a screenshot ?